# Success Event does not Fired

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, callback, jsonp

```
$.ajax('http://blog.yahoo.com/@apac3/ajax/getComment?ugcId=68197&commentCount=30&ownerGuid=IQDTYHIWBYN4PPB6DXQWU7JWN4&page=2&type=blog&.crumb=UxHpRaVVUMo&jsoncallback=?', {
        type: "GET",
        crossDomain:true, 
        async: false, 
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(comment){
            alert("myObject is " + comment.toSource());
        }
    });
```

I can see some callback is in chrome's console, however, there is some errors that making success event cannot function normally.

Does anyone know how to obtain the values in the callback?

Comment: You're requesting `jsonp`, but it doesn't seem that the server is set up to respond with a proper `jsonp` response, but rather a typical JSON response. `{"status":"SUCCESS","data":{"html":"\n<div...`.

Comment: put this in ajax call to see error. error: function( xhr, tStatus, err ) { ....

Comment: Can I get the response as a string instead of getting a json object?

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest issue is that comment is probably not an instance of a class but is either a string or is a basic JSON object. Unless you have some library which will change the way that Strings or JSON work by modifying the prototypes.